# Extract key values from one Array object and filter from other objects with the extracted values with underscore javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

```
var myArray = [{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 29
}, {
    "name": "Anna Smith",
    "age": 24
}];

var myAnotherArray = [{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 29
}, {
    "name": "Anna Smith",
    "age": 24
}, {
    "name": "Peter Jones",
    "age": 39
}, {
    "name": "Gabby",
    "age": 24
}, {
    "name": "Julian",
    "age": 29
}, {
    "name": "George",
    "age": 39
}];
```

*I want to extact all age values from first array and then filter extracted values  of age from second array.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pluck` to get the array of all the `age` from `myArray`.
And then you can use `filter`, to filter the another array based on the age.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8ypq7tdj/)

```js
var myArray = [{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 29
}, {
  "name": "Anna Smith",
  "age": 24
}];


var myAnotherArray = [{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 29
}, {
  "name": "Anna Smith",
  "age": 24
}, {
  "name": "Peter Jones",
  "age": 39
}, {
  "name": "Gabby",
  "age": 24
}, {
  "name": "Julian",
  "age": 29
}, {
  "name": "George",
  "age": 39
}];

var ages = _.pluck(myArray, 'age');

var filtered = _.filter(myAnotherArray, function(i, l) {
  return _.contains(ages, i.age);
});
console.log(filtered);
document.write(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```